# GRPC call for a service which is inside a subdirectory? (Android grpc client)

Tags: grpc, subdirectory, grpc-java, grpc-web, grpc-kotlin

This question is similar to below but my issue is with Android grpc client
[How can I make a GRPC call for a service which is inside a subdirectory? (in .Net Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71605692/how-can-i-make-a-grpc-call-for-a-service-which-is-inside-a-subdirectory-in-ne)

I am getting 404 error while accessing the grpc streaming api :

```
UNIMPLEMENTED: HTTP status code 404
    invalid content-type: text/html
    headers: Metadata(:status=404,content-length=1245,content-type=text/html,server=Microsoft-IIS/10.0,request-id=5154500d-fb58-7903-65d6-3d3711129101,strict-transport-security=max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload,alt-svc=h3=":443",h3-29=":443",x-preferredroutingkeydiagnostics=1,x-calculatedfetarget=PS2PR02CU003.internal.outlook.com,x-backendhttpstatus=404,x-calculatedbetarget=PUZP153MB0788.APCP153.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM,x-backendhttpstatus=404,x-rum-validated=1,x-proxy-routingcorrectness=1,x-proxy-backendserverstatus=404,x-feproxyinfo=MA0PR01CA0051.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM,x-feefzinfo=MAA,ms-cv=DVBUUVj7A3ll1j03ERKRAQ.1.1,x-feserver=PS2PR02CA0054,x-firsthopcafeefz=MAA,x-powered-by=ASP.NET,x-feserver=MA0PR01CA0051,date=Tue, 11 Oct 2022 06:24:18 GMT)
```

The issue is that the /subdirectory_path is getting ignored by the service in the final outgoing call.
Here's the code I am using to create the grpc channel in android (gives 404)

```
   val uri =  Uri.parse("https://examplegrpcserver.com/subdirectory_path")
    private val channel = let {
        val builder = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(uri.host+uri.path)
        if (uri.scheme == "https") {
            builder.useTransportSecurity()
        } else {
            builder.usePlaintext()
        }
        builder.executor(Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor()).build()
    }
```

The uri is correct since it works with web client.
For web client the channel is defined like this (working)

```
 var handler = new SubdirectoryHandler(httpHandler, "/subdirectory_path");
            var userToken = "<token string>";

            var grpcWebHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(handler);

            using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://examplegrpcserver.com", new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = grpcWebHandler,
                Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((context, metadata) =>
                {
                    metadata.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {userToken}");
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }))
            });
```

I tried to inject the subdirectory_path in the uri for my android client but unable to find appropriate api. grpc-kotlin doesn't expose the underlying http-client used in the channel.

Could someone please help me with this issue, how can I specify the subdirectory_path? (before the service and method name)

Comment: Did you find a way to have this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for an RPC is fixed by the `.proto` definition. Adding prefixes to the path is unsupported.

The URI passed to `forTarget()` points to the resource containing the *addresses* to connect to. So the fully-qualified form is normally of the form `dns:///example.com`. If you specified a host in the URI like `dns://1.1.1.1/example.com`, then that would mean "look up example.com at the DNS server 1.1.1.1." But there's no place to put a path prefix in the target string, as that path would only be used for address lookup, not actual RPCs.

If the web client supports path prefixes, that is a feature specific to it. It would also be using a tweaked grpc protocol that requires translation to normal backends.